# Unable to Connect to Oracle Database 11g via JDBC

Tags: java, jdbc, oracle11g

I am not able to connect to oracle Database from my machine , but can connect to same DB through SQL developer. I am getting the following exception

> java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: Connection reset by peer:
>   socket write error    at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:428)    at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.(PhysicalConnection.java:536)
>     at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.(T4CConnection.java:228)
>     at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:32)
>     at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:521)   at
>   oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource.getPhysicalConnection(OracleDataSource.java:280)
>     at
>   oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource.getConnection(OracleDataSource.java:207)
>     at
>   oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource.getConnection(OracleDataSource.java:157)
>     at OrgHierarchy.DBTest.main(DBTest.java:39)

I can also telnet to same DB URL and port.

Other Details:   Windows XP , Oracle 11g 11.0.2

thanks.

Comment: I would check the network first.

Comment: I am not denying with that possibility , but surprising thing is taht i can connect to same DB via SQL developer as i mentioned in the question. **Strange but true**

Comment: The SQL developer runs on the same machine as the java application which can't connect? If this true - check firewall settings (maybe there are differences security settings set for java.exe, sqldeveloper.exe and telnet.exe) or disable firewalls for testing purposes at all.

Comment: Another possibility is that your JDBC connection string is invalid.

Comment: You are probably using a different tnsnames.ora file.